# Two loading sprites on Android

Tags: bug, search, android-app

When I am using my phone and searching for anything and then press the search button sometimes two loading sprites show sometimes just one I assume there is only many to be one?

App version: 1.0.52

[image]

Comment: Those loading sprites are from different entity: the smaller one is from a library for pull-to-refresh, and the bigger one is from the question list (when empty/few entries). I agree though that it's one too many.